# lernen und erlernen

Tags: meaning, verb, meaning-in-context

Welche Nuance bringt erlernen im Vergleich zu lernen ?

> Im Spielkasino könnte man wunderbar erlernen, wie die Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung funktioniert.

bzw.

> Im Spielkasino könnte man wunderbar lernen, wie die Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung funktioniert.

Können wir eine Regel hervorheben, die eine allgemeine Bedeutung des Prefixes *er-* erleuchtert ?